# Issue with eSIM Implementation: Dialog Prompt Not Installing SIM Android

Tags: android, reactjs, flutter

I'm currently working on implementing eSIM functionality in my Android application, and I've encountered an issue with the code I've written. Here's the relevant code snippet:

[image]

```
    static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION = 
     "download_subscription";
       static final String LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION = 
        "com.your.company.lpa.permission.BROADCAST";
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @ Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!action.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            return;
        }
        resultCode = getResultCode();
        detailedCode = intent.getIntExtra(
            EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE,
            0 /* defaultValue*/);

        // If the result code is a resolvable error, call startResolutionActivity
        if (resultCode == EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_RESOLVABLE_ERROR) {
            PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getContext(), 0 /* requestCode */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
            mgr.startResolutionActivity(
                activity,
                0 /* requestCode */,
                intent,
                callbackIntent);
        }

        resultIntent = intent;
      } 
      };
     context.registerReceiver(receiver,
    new IntentFilter(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION),
    LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION /* broadcastPermission*/,
    null /* handler */);

    // Download subscription asynchronously.
    DownloadableSubscription sub = DownloadableSubscription
    .forActivationCode(code /* encodedActivationCode*/);
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    getContext(), 0 /* requestCode */, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    mgr.downloadSubscription(sub, true /* switchAfterDownload */,
    callbackIntent);
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the code runs, it shows a dialog asking "Allow your carrier to download the SIM," but when I press "Yes," it doesn't seem to install the SIM as expected.

I've checked the code, but I can't figure out what might be causing this issue. Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem and successfully install the eSIM after the user grants permission?

Comment: Getting follwoing exception

[PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
2023-08-29 11:10:35.356  2617-15390 EuiccGoogle             com.google.android.euicc             E  [385] UiccLogicalChannel.open: selectResponse is null. Unlocked for aid: D2760001180002FF34100089C0026E01
2023-08-29 11:10:35.358  2617-15390 EuiccGoogle             com.google.android.euicc             E  [385] EuiccGoogleUpdater.getOsVersion: Cannot get OS version

Comment: Did you resolve this one? @Mahammad

Comment: @MuhammadZubairAshraf Depends on test profile you are using the one's listed in the google docs does not seem to work. If you are a carrier then you need to provide them your SHA256 public key by running ./gradlew signingReport. They will add this key in the e-sim profile as metadata.

Comment: Hello, anyone can install eSIM on android?

Comment: @MuhammadZubairAshraf Did you find the solution i am also flutter developer and stuck with this problem.

Comment: @danish To install esim directly you should Register SHA256 with Carrier.

Comment: SHA1 is registered with Carrier but still it gives error. 
Carrier Privileges not granted to this package.

Comment: Hi, do you guys know if LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION is mandatory?